# Appcelerator Titanium App reading JSON from a wordpress website

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, titanium, appcelerator

So iv'e been searching everywhere to get an Titanium app to read JSON from a wordpress website,
Im getting an error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

not sure how to fix

but here is the code i have

app.js:

```
// Creates a tab group with Titanium.UI API.
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

// Create the window "mainWin"
var mainWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow ({
    title: "Most Recent Blog Posts", // Set the title
    backgroundColor: "#fff", // Set the background color to white
    url: "wordpress.js" // Link to file which will handle the code for the window
});

// Create the tab "mainTab"
var mainTab = Titanium.UI.createTab ({
    title: "Posts", // Title of the tab: "SUYS"
    window: mainWin // We will create the window "mainWin"
});

// Add the tab to our tab group
tabGroup.addTab(mainTab);
tabGroup.open();
```

wordpress.js

```
// Create variable "win" to refer to current window
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

// Function loadTweets()
function loadMessage()
{
    // Empty array "rowData" for our tableview
    var rowData = [];

    // Create our HTTP Client and name it "loader"
    var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    // Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
    loader.open("GET","http://http://localhost/wordpress/?json=get_posts");

    // Runs the function when the data is ready for us to process
    loader.onload = function() 
    {
        var message = eval('('+this.responseText+')');

        alert('loaded');

        for (var i = 0; i < message.posts.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(message.posts[i].post_title);
            var tweet = message.posts[i].post_content; // The tweet message
            var user = message.posts[i].author.name; // The screen name of the user
            var avatar = message.posts[i].user_avatar; // The profile image
            // Create a row and set its height to auto
            var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto'});

            // Create the view that will contain the text and avatar
            var post_view = Titanium.UI.createView({
                height:'auto', 
                layout:'vertical',
                top:5,
                right:5,
                bottom:5,
                left:5
            });
            // Create image view to hold profile pic
            var av_image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                url:avatar, // the image for the image view
                top:0,
                left:0,
                height:48,
                width:48
            });
            post_view.add(av_image);
            // Create the label to hold the screen name
            var user_lbl = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text:user,
                left:54,
                width:120,
                top:-48,
                bottom:2,
                height:16,
                textAlign:'left',
                color:'#444444',
                font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:14,fontWeight:'bold'}
            });
            post_view.add(user_lbl);
            // Create the label to hold the tweet message
            var tweet_lbl = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text:tweet,
                left:54,
                top:0,
                bottom:2,
                height:'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                textAlign:'left',
                font:{fontSize:14}
            });
            post_view.add(tweet_lbl);
            // Add the post view to the row
            row.add(post_view);
            // Give each row a class name
            row.className = "item"+i;
            // Add row to the rowData array
            rowData[i] = row;
        }
        // Create the table view and set its data source to "rowData" array
        var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({data:rowData});
        //Add the table view to the window
        win.add(tableView);
    };
    // Send the HTTP request
    loader.send();
}
loadMessage();
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: That might not be the solution, but could you write `var message = JSON.parse(this.responseText)` instead of `var message = eval('('+this.responseText+')');`, so we can investigate further?

Comment: Two other things, your `loader.open()` contains double 'http://' and instead of `console.log()` you may want to write `Ti.API.debug()`

Comment: [Eval is evil..](http://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil/), but regardless, have you confirmed what is coming down from the site is real, well formed JSON?